# cant create function app, get "This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription"

Tags: azure-functions

The region is North Europe.  Other companies I know have no problem creating function apps in this regiobn.

I have tried creating hello world http trigger function app via visual studio publish, and also directly manually in azure portal - same error.

We have several azure subscriptions which have lots of resources in them.  They are not "trial" subscriptions.

The exact error is:

{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","details":[{"code":"ValidationForResourceFailed","message":"Validation failed for a resource. Check 'Error.Details[0]' for more information.","details":[{"code":"SubscriptionIsOverQuotaForSku","message":"This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU."}]}],"message":"The template deployment 'Microsoft.Web-FunctionApp-Portal-01b72bda-xxx' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'ed86df9b-5636-4adf-9e6c-4659d4axxxx'. See inner errors for details."}

I selected default options, including "windows" not linux for the OS.

Details
Subscription. xxx
Resource Group. fapp1
Name FATest2
Runtime stack .NET 6
Hosting Storage (New)
Storage account swhfapp19ee9
Plan (New)
Plan type Consumption (Serverless)
Name ASP-swhfapp1-a654
Operating System Windows
Region North Europe
SKU Dynamic
Monitoring (New)
Application Insights
Enabled
Name FATest2
Region North Europe

Any ideas what the cause of this error is, or what the fix is?

Answer (score 3):

Please check if my findings are helpful,

---

*I can able to reproduce the issue while creating Azure function in North Europe as shown below,*

[image]

As i can see its available in the [**`Product category`**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?regions=europe-north&products=functions) that we can create function apps in the same region.

[image]

- ***To do that If you are owner of that subscription you can register the resource which you want to create as mentioned in this*** [**`MS DOC`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types).

**NOTE:-** *I do have contributor role in our subscription only.*
For more information please refer the Below links:-

- **MICROSOFT Q&A DISCUSSION FOR SIMILAR ISSUES**|[***Error - "This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/736717/linux-app-service-with-php-error-34this-region-has.html) & [***Why do I get "location is not available for resource type"***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/244/why-do-i-get-location-is-not-available-for-resourc.html) .